# python import tf -> rosdep2.core.InvalidData osx-homebrew.yaml

Tags: ros, osx, ros-jade, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've somehow messed up the ability to import tf:

(starting from a clean .bashrc)

```
$ source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from listener import TransformListener, TransformerROS
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 30, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest(PKG)
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 208, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 393, in parse_manifest_file
    _static_rosdep_view = init_rospack_interface()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 58, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 127, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 607, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 508, in load_cached_sources_list
    return parse_sources_data(cache_data, origin=cache_index, model=model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 366, in parse_sources_data
    raise InvalidData("line:\n\t%s\n%s"%(line, e), origin=origin)
rosdep2.core.InvalidData: line:
    yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
unsupported pickle protocol: 4
```

I cleaned out my ~/.ros/rosdep and ran rosdep update on it, but no change.

Another user account on same system was able to import tf fine, but then I ran `rosdep update` in it and now it has the same error.

If I scp the sources.cache from another system that hasn't been rosdep updated I can make it work again.

Ubuntu 14.04.4, jade, rosdep 0.11.4-1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229414/python-import-tf--%3E-rosdep2.core.invaliddata-osx-homebrew.yaml/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 'import tf' was a distraction that delayed finding this issue which is about python 3 pickle incompatibility with python 2:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/379

And my rosdep does have `#!/usr/bin/python3` in it and is in /usr/local/bin (but on two other systems it just has a `#!/usr/bin/python` and is only in /usr/bin/rosdep, reports the same version).  There is also a /usr/bin/rosdep but the local bin takes precedence.

This answer http://answers.ros.org/question/42818/tutorial-building-a-ros-package-rosdep-experienced-an-internal-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-copy/ shows how to remove the wrong rosdep:

```
sudo pip uninstall rosdep
Not uninstalling rosdep at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

Therefore it was installed by easy_install, and has to be removed by hand.  There were a lot of ros files in /usr/local/bin (rosversion, roslocate, rosinstall, rosdistro, rosco), I'll remove all of them:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ros*
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/catkin*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ros*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
```

I'm not sure where they came from, they were all dated December 2nd, and I must not have run rosdep update since then until yesterday.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2